# Compiling mpich2 on OSX (and targeting the OSX 10.5 SDK)

Tags: macos, compatibility, compile

I am compiling [mpich2 1.4.1p1](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpich2/) for OSX and using -sysroot to direct the compilers to link against the SDK for 10.5. I do the following in a script to avoid typing this all out every time. As you can see, I've gotten desperate in the environment variables and using everyone I can find in their README (except fortran ones which I am disabling).

```
export CFLAGS="-isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5"
export CPPLAGS="-isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5"
export LDFLAGS="-isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5"
export CXXFLAGS="-isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5"
export LIBS="-isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5" 
../configure --with-pm=gforker --enable-fast=O3 --disable-f77 --disable-fc --prefix=/opt/mpich2/64/
```

Unfortunately, the compiled version does not link with SOME of the libraries in the OSX10.5 directories.

```
otool -L /opt/mpich2/64/bin/mpiexec
    /opt/local/lib/libxml2.2.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.6.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.3)
    /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 111.1.4)
    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

The iconv library in the SDK is 7.0.0,

```
otool -L /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib 
    /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 111.0.0)
```

I'm trying to distribute against this application and most of the OSX machines I've tested on here at the lab have libiconv version 7.0.0. I do not want this to be a requirement in my distribution.

Grep'ing the source of mpich, I can see the logs and makefiles that are using the wrong version, with a spattering of `-L/opt/local/lib/` sprinkled throughout the hydra and doxygen build process.

What environment variables am I missing? I realize this is a complex build script and someone skipping a convention is of high probability. I'll continue to hunt through the makefiles. And I'll see if using `sed` to replace every instance of `-L/opt/local/lib/` with the path I really want fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to build 1.4 and 1.3 to see if the issue resides there.

Thankfully 1.4 built and ran fine. It looks as though `iconv` is statically linked in that version of `mpich2` --running `otool -L mpiexec` did not even include `libiconv` as a dependency.